# How to inject environments variable into Grails GSP file?

Tags: grails, environment-variables, gsp

Say I have the following Grails (2.3.6) GSP file:

```
<%
    String env = ??? how to get from the -Dgrails.env arg below?
%>
<head>
    <!-- head stuff -->
</head>
<body>
    <h2>I am running in the ${env} environment!</h2>
</body>
```

Now let's say I run my Grails app with different environments specified:

> grails -Dgrails.env=dev run-app
>
> grails -Dgrails.env=fizz run-app
>
> grails -Dgrails.env=buzz run-app

...etc. How can I inject the `-Dgrails.env` argument into the `env` variable in the GSP file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%
    String env = grails.util.Environment.current.name
%>

My Environment = ${env}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define a block in your config.groovy to match the environment you pass in `-Dgrails.env=foo`

```
environments {
   foo {
       setting = "bar"
   }
}
```

Then this will be available as part of your configuration settings and they can easily be accessed using the if taglib.

```
<g:if env="foo">
    <!-- Markup to include ONLY when in foo -->
</g:if>
```

or you can grab anything from that config block.

```
${grailsApplication.config}
```

Comment: Thanks @cfaddict (+1) - Is there a way to access `env` in Groovy (inside the GSP) like I have it? Instead of putting stuff inside `<g:if>` tags?

Comment: ${grailsApplication.ENVIRONMENT}

http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html#ENVIRONMENT